# Correctly sizing an`<svg> element inside a flex box without overflow

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

Trying to get a layout of an HTML page with flex boxes like

```
[navigation] [[button][stretchable svg][button]]
```

such that [navigation] and [button] take as much space as needed and the stretchable svg gets the rest, I am forced to give the stretchable svg a `width="1"` or another small number, since otherwise the row is wrappend into:

```
[navigation] 
[[button][stretchable svg][button]]
```

**Question**: Why is the `width="..."` needed to make sure the second block does not get wrapped to the next row?

Here is the code of [the jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e38aoh0c/4/) for reference:

```html
<div class="navi">
  <a>some button text</a>
</div>
<div class="plotWrapper">
  <div class="plotRow">
    <a class="scrollButton">left</a>
    <!-- broken layout without width="1" -->
    <svg id=xplot width="1"></svg>
    <a class="scrollButton">right</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}
svg {
  background: yellow;
  height: 200px;
}
.plotWrapper {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
.plotRow {
  display: flex;
}
.navi {
  border: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
}
#xplot {
  flex-grow: 100;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you are running into is the default sizing of elements in HTML. As of HTML5, the concensus is that the default sizing of an inline SVG tag is [300px by 150px](https://css-tricks.com/scale-svg/#:%7E:text=The%20default%20300%C3%97150,the%20default%20size%20for%20SVG). By setting the width to 1px, the flex layout can shrink it as much as it wants. Without setting width to 1px, the layout takes the default width of 300px resulting in the line break in more narrow widths as the 300px SVG does not fit in the same line as the header.